# I cannot import and use SwingFxUtils

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I am using Intelj with `Maven`, my version is 19.

I tried almost everything, but i cannot figure it out.

- i tried to add the dependecies to my `pom.xml`;
- i tried to add library to my project;
- i tried to requires `javafx.swing` in the `module-info`;
- i tried to install the file jar.

This is what happen when i try to add it on my file maven:

[image]

Comment: `<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-swing -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
    <version>19-ea+11</version>
</dependency>
` from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-swing/19-ea+11

Comment: Once you have the correct version of the dependency (which **exactly** matches the versions of all your other JavaFX dependencies), you need to reimport the maven project into the IDE, you can see that `M` icon in the top right of your image, press that.  If the import fails for any reason, the IDE will tell you.

Comment: Mixing JavaFX and Swing is not a beginner task, are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: @jewelsea, I think that SwingFxUtils has other stuff in it.  I saw one example that was using it to save a WritableImage to disk.

Comment: Note there's virtually no reason to use an early-access version of JavaFX 19. The latest stable release is `19`, with `19.0.1` planned to be released on January 17 of this year.